# Best way to find x

Tags: inequality

Sorry that this is simple, but I am getting a bit confused.

$$\frac{5.8}{4.35} = \frac{x+.45}{x}$$

What is the correct way to solve for x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $4.35 x$ to clear the denominators; this leaves you with the linear equation

$$5.8 x = 4.35 x + 1.9575$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x\cdot 5.8}{4.35} = x+.45$$

$$x\cdot (\frac{5.8}{4.35} - 1) = .45$$

Divide by the term in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{5.8}{4.35}=\dfrac{x+0.45}{x}$$
Cross-multiply - you get
$$5.8(x)=4.35(x+0.45)$$
Use the distributive property on the RHS and then you get your answer by bringing all the $x$ terms to one side, and then dividing.

Answer (score 0):

Just cross multiply

```
5.8/4.35=x+0.45/x
```

to

```
5.8x=4.35(x+0.45)
```

Bring all the x terms to one side and continue,you will get it